Adding a second sidebar in Cavin theme WordPress website
So my website is using Cavin theme.this theme only has the option of one sidebar but I want to add another. I created a child theme, tried editing the code but when I add the second one, the previous sidebar made with elementary disappears. Can someone please tell what to do?
I registered the second sidebar in function.php and added it in single.php too.
I created a Child theme,
registered the second sidebar in function.php and added it in single.php too.
I cannot the second one using elementary because I do not have a pro version of it to add it in posts page.
The second sidebar is for posts page only. Not the other pages.
And changing themes isn't an option.
functions.php:
function register_custom_sidebars() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Left Sidebar',
        'id'            => 'sidebar-left',
        'description'   => 'Widgets in this area will be shown on the left side of posts.',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h3>',
    ));
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_custom_sidebars' );



single.php:
 <?php
get_header();
?>
<main class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="single-post-wrapper">
    <?php
    /* Start the Loop */
    while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();
        
        $sidebar_position = rivax_get_sidebar_position('single-post', 'none-narrow');
        if ($sidebar_position == 'elementor') {
            ?>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        } else {
            ?>
            <?php get_template_part('template-parts/post/single-hero-outside'); ?>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="page-content-wrapper <?php echo 'sidebar-' . $sidebar_position; ?>">
                    
                    <div class="content-container">
                           
                            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('single-content'); ?>>
                                <?php get_template_part('template-parts/post/single-hero-inside'); ?>
                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
                                <?php get_template_part('template-parts/post/update-date'); ?>
                                <?php get_template_part('template-parts/post/tags'); ?>
                            </article>
                            <?php get_template_part('template-parts/post/share'); ?>
                            <?php get_template_part('template-parts/post/author-box'); ?>
                            <?php get_template_part('template-parts/post/next-prev-posts'); ?>
                            <?php comments_template(); ?>
                        </div>
                        
                        <?php if ($sidebar_position == 'left' || $sidebar_position == 'right') : ?>
                            <aside class="sidebar-container <?php if (rivax_get_option('sticky-sidebar')) echo 'sticky'; ?>">
                                <!-- Load left sidebar -->
                                <aside class="sidebar-container <?php if (rivax_get_option('sticky-sidebar')) echo 'sticky'; ?>">
                                <!-- Load left sidebar -->
                                <?php get_template_part('sidebar-left'); ?>
                                </aside>
                                <!-- Load right sidebar -->
                                <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                            </aside>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php get_template_part('template-parts/post/content-bottom'); ?>
            <?php
        }
    endwhile; // End of the loop.
    ?>
    </div>
</main>
<?php
if (rivax_get_option('post-reading-progress-indicator')) {
    echo '<div class="post-reading-progress-indicator"><span></span></div>';
}

get_footer();



Could you please share the code you are using in functions.php and single.php because it helps in understanding the issue.

@NarendraSishodiya I did.
